# Rails - Malicious user overriding user name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, security, attributes

Imagine you have a user model with a user name and several other attributes. A user will only be able to set a username while singing up, not later when editing his profile.

Still, the :user_name attribute needs to accessible through attr_accessible in the user model for the registration form.

This makes me wonder whether a malicious user could change the form that allows him to edit his profile, and change an input name to user_name and thereby in fact change it upon submit.

Am I right about this, i.e. could a malicious user do that or will Ruby find out somehow that the form was altered? If this is a security issue, how can I always reset the user name in my update method? Is there a rails way of differentiating between accessible and accessible but non-editable attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible due to Rails' CSRF counter measures. See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).

You should have the following line in your application controller:

```
protect_from_forgery :secret => "123456789012345678901234567890..."
```

Also have a look at the following article for further information on [XSS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss), which describes in some detail what is possible and counter-measures to take.

Always `sanitize()` input.